# "Can't add self as subview" crash (with sample code) when view not adding itself to its subview

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I can reproduce this problem with a simple project ([Github Project](https://github.com/ldesegur/CantAddSelfAsSubview.git))

The mainstoryboard has an embedded `ViewController` transitioned to by a segue from an initial `NavigationController`. The Nav Controller is the initial root controller and pointed as such in the storyboard view.

The AppDelegate class `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method instantiates another Navigation Controller and adds a root viewcontroller programmatically:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let mainvc = MainViewController()
    let mainnc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainvc)

    self.window?.rootViewController = mainnc
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

The MainViewController instantiated above has the following code.

```
class MainViewController : UITableViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(nibName:nil, bundle:nil)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tableView = UITableView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.view.bounds.size.width, height:self.view.bounds.size.height), style:.plain)
        self.tableView = tableView
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(white:0.85, alpha:1)
        tableView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"nephews")

        self.view.addSubview(tableView) // CRASH
    }

}
```

When running the code, I am getting:

> 2018-03-15 13:35:57.083953-0700 CantAddSelfAsSubview[20953:14423557]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010957912b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105900f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001095ee245 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000106267582 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 122
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001062c6341 -[UITableView _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 127
    5   CantAddSelfAsSubview                0x0000000104fdf310 _T020CantAddSelfAsSubview20MyMainViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyF + 1312
    6   CantAddSelfAsSubview                0x0000000104fdf6c4 _T020CantAddSelfAsSubview20MyMainViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyFTo + 36
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010634546c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1235
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010638cffc -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 68
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010638d338 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 153
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010638e44f -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 841
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010638f6d3 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001065ea4e2 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010626ea6d -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1439
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010cb5e61c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 159
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010cb627ad _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 401
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010cae986c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 364
    17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010cb16946 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 500
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001061b826a __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 141
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010951c05c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010950083b __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 203
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109500014 __CFRunLoopRun + 1300
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001094ff889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010bd069c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010619d5d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
    25  CantAddSelfAsSubview                0x0000000104fe2027 main + 55
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a717d81 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Since I am not adding a view to itself, it seems the problem is somewhere else.

I've read many comments on SO with similar issues but no repro code. Some people fear that there is a bug in the NavController when the animation is not done. How do I control the animation of the segue as it's automatically managed by the first nav controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the incorrect code in `viewDidLoad`, `self.view`, `self.tableView`, and `tableView` are all the same view. Hence the error.

This is a `UITableViewController`. It already has a table view. Do not create another one. Update `viewDidLoad` as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(white:0.85, alpha:1)
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"nephews")
}
```

You also do not need to add any of those `init` methods.

Comment: Thanks. Is there really no need for this `tableView.delegate = self` and `tableView.dataSource = self`?

Comment: Correct. `UITableViewController` makes itself the table view's data source and delegate automatically. One other thing you do need to change is the your code in the app delegate that creates `MainViewController`. You should call the initializer that takes the table view style, not the default empty initializer.

Comment: @Laurent Though you do need to implement the various data source and delegate methods in `MainViewController` for the table view to be useful.

Comment: +1, I was trying to be concise just to point out the issue. My main project is much more meaty :-) I'll use `MainViewController(style: .plain)`